# Make flexbox rows take up 100% of browser height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout on my page.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <section id="wrapper">
            <section id="flexbox">
                <section id="page1">  </section>
                <section id="page2">  </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the sections page1 and page2 to fill the entire browser height. I want to see page1 then scroll down to see page2.

**Additional notes:**

body and html heights are set to 100%.

Wrapper has block styling.

The flexbox has no-wrap and is set to columns.

Comment: where is your CSS?

Comment: Just give each section a height of `100vh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `100vh` to the each element.

you can read more about it here [Viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

```css
#page1,
#page2 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#page1 {
  background: #ff0;
}

#page2 {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <section id="flexbox">
    <section id="page1"></section>
    <section id="page2"></section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Ugh it was a parent container that I left out giving me grief. Thanks